# VBA: Loops and Offsets in Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba, excel

**(Find the updated version in the answers)**

I have a code which is working well but a little bit slow and I would like to know how to make it more efficient. The fact that the code includes two loops could be one of the possible reasons.

Below you can find the whole code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Columns.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("TABLE[COLUMN]")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngCell As Range, urg As Range, drg As Range, u As Integer, d As Integer
    d = 0
    u = 0
    Set urg = Target.Cells(1, 1)
    Set drg = Target.Cells(Target.Count, 1)
    Do While drg.Offset(d, -13) = drg.Offset(d + 1, -13)
        d = d + 1
    Loop
    Do While urg.Offset(u, -13) = urg.Offset(u - 1, -13)
        u = u - 1
    Loop
    For Each rngCell In Me.Range(Target.Offset(u, 0), Target.Offset(d, 0))
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rngCell.Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

The code is inserting the same input value (column 13) for all the adjacent cells with the same ID (column 1). For example, if I would input a 3 for Column13 in either ID002 or ID003:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3... Column13       Column13
ID001   1       1          1          >   1
ID002   2       2          2          >   3
ID002   3       3          2          >   3
ID003   4       4          4          >   4
```

Once I unput the value, it takes a few seconds to recalculate the adjacent cells so I would appreciate whatever advice that will make this code work faster.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `Offset` calls and worksheet accesses are probably what's killing you in performance - pull all the values you need into an array and work with that.

Comment: Also, you can just set the values at the end `rngCell.value=Me.Range(Target.Offset(u, 0), Target.Offset(d, 0)).value`, making rngCell the same depth etc as d-u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(2nd and last update)**

I updated the code with @Dan Donoghue's idea (thanks!).

And this is the result:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Columns.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("TABLE[COLUMN]")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim u As Long, d As Long
    u = Range("TABLE[ID]").Find(Range("TABLE[ID]").Cells(Target.Row - 1, 1)).Row
    d = Range("TABLE[ID]").Find(Range("TABLE[ID]").Cells(Target.Row + Target.Count - 2, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range(Target.Cells(1).Offset(u - Target.Row, 0), Target.Cells(1).Offset(d - Target.Row, 0)).Value = Target.Cells(1).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

What I appreciate from this last update is that it made the code look lighter. However, it is working slightly slower compared to the previous update.

I set a timer in all the versions that I posted so far and I ran the code for 3 rows in column 13 which belong to identical ID to test how fast the code performs in the same conditions.

My initial code: 0.55 seconds.

1st update (`For-Next` out, `Offset` out & `Array` in): 0.19 seconds.

2nd update (`Do While` out & `Find` in): 0.20 seconds.

Since I cannot beat the 20 seconds time, I think I will use this version as the code is more clean.

Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Nice application of the theory, neat and concise :). Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for this loop

```
For Each rngCell In Me.Range(Target.Offset(u, 0), Target.Offset(d, 0))
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rngCell.Value = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Next
```

You can assign the `Target.Value` to all the cells at once.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.Range(Target.Offset(u, 0), Target.Offset(d, 0)).Value = Target.Cells(1).Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Suggest to replace `Target.Value` with `Target.Cells(1).Value` to replicate what original OP's code is doing. If the Target range has more than one cells and the range of ID's has a higher number of cells than the Target range, then some cells in [COLUMN] will be filled with `#N/A`

Comment: Thanks both for the initial advice and the consequent correction!

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids the loops and uses the advantages of the Excel Table (ListObject excel object)

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lobTrg As ListObject
Dim aIDs As Variant
Dim bPos As Byte

    If Target.Columns.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Rem Application Setting - OFF
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Rem Set List Object
    Set lobTrg = Me.ListObjects("TABLE")

    Rem Work with the ListObject Methods & Properties
    With lobTrg

        Rem Validate Target Range vs ListObject Field [COLUMN]
        If Not (Intersect(Target, .ListColumns("COLUMN").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing) Then

            Rem Remove Active Filters from the ListObject
            If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Range.AutoFilter

            Rem Set Array with ID's Affected by the Changes in Field [COLUMN]
            aIDs = Target.Offset(, -13).Value2
            aIDs = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aIDs)

            Rem Filter ListObject using the ID's Array
            bPos = .ListColumns("COLUMN").Index - 13
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=bPos, Criteria1:=aIDs, Operator:=xlFilterValues

            Rem Update Field [COLUMN] value for all the ID's
            .ListColumns("COLUMN").DataBodyRange _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Target.Cells(1).Value2

            Rem Removes Filters from List Object
            .Range.AutoFilter

    End If: End With

    Rem Application Setting - ON
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[ListObject Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839458.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx),

Comment: I had bad experiences with ListObjects when running codes in Mac OS. Also, it means a completely new logic for me but I strongly appreciate your help and effort, thanks so much @EMM

Answer (score 0):

**(1st update)**

I rebuilded the code with your suggestions.

This is the result:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim u As Long, d As Long
Dim id As Variant
If Target.Columns.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("TABLE[COLUMN]")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    id = Me.Range("TABLE[ID]").Value
    u = Target.Row - 1
    d = Target.Row + Target.Count - 2
    Do While id(u, 1) = id(u - 1, 1)
        u = u - 1
    Loop
    Do While id(d, 1) = id(d + 1, 1)
        d = d + 1
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range(Target.Cells(1).Offset(u - Target.Row + 1, 0), Target.Cells(1).Offset(d - Target.Row + 1, 0)).Value = Target.Cells(1).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

I applied the changes by blocks. First, I removed the loop For-Next which was unnecessary and slightly improved the performance. Secondly, I replaced the `Offset` which was looking for the ID with an array but it did not really make any difference.

Let's go for a second round, any other idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

With those do while loops, you can possibly use the find function.

Here is a rough idea of what I mean.

In a sheet in column A put the following in row 1 down to 9

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Go into the VBE and bring up the debug window using CTRL-G and enter the following:

```
?range("A1:A9").Find(1).address
```

It will return $A$4 as the first instance of "1"

Now this itself is no good to you because you want to detect when it NO LONGER equals something.

No problem (Assuming your data is grouped).

Now put this into the VBE:

```
?range("A1:A9").Findprevious.Address
```

When you press enter you will get $A$6 which is the address of the last occurrence, we can simply offset this like this:

```
?range("A1:A9").Findprevious.offset(1,0).Address
```

and you will get the next cell's address of $A$7 ie when it no longer equals what you feed in.

Hopefully there is something in this that you can apply to remove those other loops.

You do need both of these together though as the first line sets up the search:

```
?range("A1:A9").Find(1).address
?range("A1:A9").Findprevious.offset(1,0).Address
```